# Pandas groupby and find difference between max and min

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe. I have aggregated as below. But, I want to difference them as max value - min values

[image]

```
dnm=df.groupby('Type').agg({'Vehicle_Age': ['max','min']})
```

Expect:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`np.ptp`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ptp.html), this does the `max - min` calculation for you:

```
df.groupby('Type').agg({'Vehicle_Age': np.ptp})
```

Or,

```
df.groupby('Type')['Vehicle_Age'].agg(np.ptp)
```

If you a Series as the output.

Comment: thats a better solution and also faster then maie.. `%timeit df.groupby('Type').agg({'a': np.ptp})
1.29 ms ± 39.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)` vs `%%timeit 
grouping = df.groupby('Type')
dnm = grouping.max() - grouping.min() 1.57 ms ± 299 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)`

Comment: @adirabargil Thank you for timing, please add it to your answer and I will be happy to vote on it

Answer (score 5):

just compare the two :

```
grouping = df.groupby('Type')
dnm = grouping.max() - grouping.min()
```

@cs95's answer is the right approach and also has better timing! :

setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(100),'Type':[1 if i %2 ==0 else 0 for i in range(100)]})
```

@cs95:

```
%timeit df.groupby('Type').agg({'a': np.ptp}) 

1.29 ms ± 39.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

vs

```
%%timeit  
grouping = df.groupby('Type') 
dnm = grouping.max() - grouping.min() 

1.57 ms ± 299 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Might also be worth including your setup to create Large Df so others can compare notes on timings.

Answer (score 3):

You should perform a basic element-wise operation on the columns of the table which you can do like so:

```py
import pandas as pd

# This is just setup to replicate your example
df = pd.DataFrame([[14, 7], [15, .25], [14, 9], [13, 2], [14, 4]], index=['Large SUV', 'Mid-size', 'Minivan', 'Small', 'Small SUV'], columns = ['max', 'min'])

print(df)

#             max   min
# Large SUV   14  7.00
# Mid-size    15  0.25
# Minivan     14  9.00
# Small       13  2.00
# Small SUV   14  4.00

# This is the operation that will give you the values you want
diff = df['max'] - df['min']

print(diff)

# Large SUV     7.00
# Mid-size     14.75
# Minivan       5.00
# Small        11.00
# Small SUV    10.00
```